# indexPath.row always return 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've noticed that there are several threads about this issue but each one is depending on code so i decided to start my own thread with my piece of code. Here's the code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [articles count];
}    

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ArticleCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    Article *article = [articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = article.articleTitle;
    return cell;
}



- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showArticleDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ArticleDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.article = [articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Where is he number of rows method?

Comment: Where does it return 0? What result do you see on screen? What is it that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Fogmeister i've updated the code with my numberofrows method.

Comment: and what is articles.count then. plz answer nirvav too

Comment: @Nirav Bhatt - well, there are several articles and no matter on which one you click detail page always displays data for first articles. I used NSLog to check the value of indexPath.row and it is always 0.

Comment: Your code asks for selected indexpath. Does the tableView allows selection? What does your didSelectRowWithIndexPath delegate method do?

Comment: What is the segue triggered from? What is the sender?

Comment: Is self.tableView set properly?  Set a breakpoint in `prepareForSegue` and check the value of self.tableaview with the tableaview value in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: NSLog(@"indexPath row: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)indexPath.row]); in siege always return 0

Answer (score -1):

In your code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [articles count];
}
```

`aricles count` is zero or one. So I used NSLog to check the value of `articles count`.

`Alloc` your articles. If its `NSMutableArray` then `alloc` like this.

```
NSMutableArray *articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Set the  `@interface MyView : UIView <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>`
in the .h file

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showLocationDetails"])

    {
        LocationDetailsViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        indexPathSelected = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender].row;
        vc.location = _locationsArray[indexPathSelected];

    }
}
```

Set your segue method accordingly.

Comment: articles count returns the correct number. 
i'm using "articles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];". 
code in .h file is same. 
the method you posted returns many errors...

Comment: in .m file and in viewdidload.